# SQLite only get element if it contains specific element in row

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how do pull an element from my SQLite db only it it contains say "genre of comedy" in on of it's cols.

So for example I have a sqlite db for movies with cols. of actor, director, genre....

I'd like to grab only rows which contain genre of say "comedy"

pseudo code

```
if row contains genre === "comedy"
    var poster = rows.item(counter).poster
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Select from Movies where genre = 'comedy'
```